# Add floatValues to NSArray add then output total

Tags: iphone, floating-point, uitextfield, nsarray, uilabel

My brain is fried! I can't think.

I'm using Core Data, and this is an iPhone app just so you know.
What i am trying to do is take the floatValues (like amount paid) from text fields and them to an array, add the values in the array and output the total to a label.

For some odd reason I honestly can't think.I'm scattered brained at the moment. Please help!

Thanks in advance.
-T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSArray in Objective C stores only Objects, so you will need to convert the float integral value into an NSNumber object using the following code and of course back.

```
[arr addObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: fV]];

float total = 0.0;
for (NSNumber v in arr)
{
    total += [v floatValue];
}
```

However, you could easily create a float[] c-style array and iterate with a simple for loop over it.

Comment: Agree, there's probably not (much) better way than iterate over your values array and add them one by one. More elegant way would be to encapsulate example code above to some function or method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the array using `NSNumber` or its subclass `NSDecimalNumber`. `NSDecimalNumber`s can be added using `decimalNumberByAdding:` too.